# ubuntu nic card issue

Tags: networking, drivers

I am trying to install NIC r8168 and it shows everything installed ok. It is a brand new NIC and the lights wont come on when I plug in a ethernet. The NIC is that is not working is eth0. Why does it show the r8168 driver being used by 0? My NIC model number is ST1000SPEX if anyone is wondering.

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
r8168                 215669  0
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:cd:1e:0a:4a  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:43 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d1:1d:f6:7a  
      inet addr:192.168.1.83  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::219:d1ff:fe1d:f67a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:551467 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:145219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:409744342 (409.7 MB)  TX bytes:12233173 (12.2 MB)
      Interrupt:21 Memory:dfde0000-dfe00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22608 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:22608 (22.6 KB)
```

Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Kernel 3.0.0-12-generic

Comment: what is the print from `sudo lshw -C network`

Answer (score 1):

The ST1000SPEX NIC has a Realtek RTL8111DL chip on it, so Ubuntu will take the r8168 driver. If you have a problem with the drivers try the ones at [Realtek's official site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Answer (score 0):

While this is for 10.04 I think this will be helpful:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html

I think what you need in particular is something like:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0` (assuming that you are trying to do this from the command line).